# Where are all the options?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to make liquid and I need to go to inflow on fluid but it doesn't show. I only have four options to choose from and I should have more. I have searched everywhere and can't find the answer to this question.

This is what I have

[image]

This is what I need
[image]

Comment: In the latest blender releases, you first select flow and then you will get a lot of settings, which can decide if you want liquid or smoke or things like inflow, outflow, and geometry.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose *Flow*, you can immediately below that choose *Flow Behaviour* under *Settings*, there you have *Inflow* as an option.